# Recover a signed message using public/private key

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, private-key, public-key

I have generated public and private keys using the following commands:

- `openssl genrsa -out D:\opensslkeys\privatekey1.pem 1024`
- `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in  D:\opensslkeys\privatekey1.pem -out D:\opensslkeys\privatekey1.der -nocrypt`
- `openssl rsa -in D:\opensslkeys\privatekey1.pem -pubout -outform DER -out D:\opensslkeys\publickey1.der`

Then I wrote a Java program to sign a message and then verify it, which worked:

```
    String message = "Hello world";
    File privateKey = new File("privatekey.der");
    KeyPair keyPair = readKeyPair(privateKey, "happy".toCharArray());
    PrivateKey privkey= PrivateKeyReader.get("privatekey.der");
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");
    signature.initSign(privkey);
    signature.update(message.getBytes());
    byte [] signatureBytes=new byte[512];    
    signatureBytes= signature.sign();
    PublicKey pubk=PublicKeyReader.get("publickey.der");
    byte[] encodedPublicKey1=pubk.getEncoded();

    Signature verifier = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");
    verifier.initVerify(pubk);
    verifier.update(message.getBytes());

    if (verifier.verify(signatureBytes)) {
        System.out.println("Signature is valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Signature is invalid");
    }
```

But after verifying I need to recover the message. Please explain how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I formatted the openssl command-lines as code to make them easier to read and made some minor fixes to grammar. Please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. It would help if you edited your question to say what you meant by "recover the message" - perhaps you want to encrypt and decrypt the message rather than (or as well as) sign and verify it? Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Signing a message does not make it unreadable, so there is no "recovery" step required. The signature is a little bit of extra data that may be in the same file or may be stored separately. The signature allows the reader of the message to verify who wrote the message (via the public key that validates the signature) and that the message has not been altered.

If you want to give someone your signed message, you give them the clear-text message and the signature. They can then use your public key to validate the signature. The signature is based on a digest of the message and your private key. The validation step computes the digest of the message and validates the signature of the digest with the public key. If either the public key doesn't correspond to the private key used in the signature, or if the message digest doesn't match, then the signature is detected as invalid.

A related operation would by to encrypt a message. This definitely makes the message unreadable. The encryption would be with a public key and only the holder of the associated private key would be able to decrypt the message.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the message.

You can't 'recover' it from the signature, if that's what you're referring to. A signature is not an encryption.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This clarifies and solves my problem.Please also inform me that do we need actual unsigned message at the time of verifying as I have used in my java code in line verifier.update(message.getBytes());

Comment: @user3212372 Yes, you'd need the original message to perform verification. One of the steps in verification is computing a hash of the message. Being able to create or guess a message that can be verified allows forgery of a digital signature. This is was found to be possible with MD5, so people don't use it for signatures anymore.